# Javascript common DRY programming idioms

Tags: javascript

```
var veryLongObjectName = {};
// ...


if (!veryLongObjectName["verylongpropertyName"]) 
      veryLongObjectName["verylongpropertyName"] = 0;

if (veryLongObjectName["verylongpropertyName"]++) 
      console.log("I've seen it already");
```

I would like to make above code less verbose by changing last two lines; how can I achieve that?

Comment: By shortening the object and property names.

Comment: DRY is not about using variables, even when they have long names.

Comment: DRY is about not repeating myself; I've used long names just to point to the problem

Comment: someone doesn't like the question, but in other languages this would not be a problem

Comment: In other languages?  Aren't you the one making these long names?

Comment: @mpapec DRY has to do with not repeating the same LOGIC. But that you have to repeat the same identifiers, that you voluntarily chose, is basically unavoidable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey in other languages first condition is optional (ie. perl/php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var veryLongObjectName = {};
var obj = veryLongObjectName;
var prop = "verylongpropertyName";

if (!obj[prop]) obj[prop] = 0;

if (obj[prop]++) console.log("I've seen it already");
```

or create a function to handle what you want done:

```
function checkProp(obj, prop) {
    obj[prop] = obj[prop] || 0;
    if (obj[prop]++) console.log("I've seen it already");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using a reference.

```
var veryLongObjectName = {};
var prop = veryLongObjectName["verylongpropertyName"];

if (!prop) 
    prop = 0;

if (prop++) 
    console.log("I've seen it already");
```

Comment: you probably shouldn't use dot notation for that - he's correct in using bracket notation, just fyi :)

Comment: if the property is not an object, you won't get a reference, but you get a copy. any ops on prop later won't have any effect on original property. Am I missing something? As I can see prop here is a number.

Comment: property is number and `++` confirms that

Comment: @mpapec yes okay, then you need to pull back the calculated value.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just make shorthandles for your objects and props if they bother you:

```
var prop = 'longpropertyname';
var obj = longObjectName;
// do whatever you want with obj[prop]
```